# What is the best SSIS component for many calculations

Tags: sql, ssis

I am a novice when it comes to SSIS and I am building a small package that will process roughly 12m rows and insert them into 2 tables (parent-child). The source and destination is SQL Server.

Many calculations have to be performed with a lot of nested logic. I was wondering what the best/recommended approach for this would be. My options as I see them are to either include the calculations into my source stored procedure using CASE WHEN statements, perform the logic and calculations in a derived column component or to perform all the calculations in a script component. I am leaning towards including all the logic and calculations in 1 script component for all the attributes as this would be easier for me to maintain when compared to the other 2 methods and I believe faster when compared to including the calculations in the source query. There are about 30 calculated columns. The maths and logic is simple but as I said the logic is nested.

Would this be correct or is there another component I should consider?

Thanks

Comment: Why do you say that including it in the script component would be faster than doing it in the source stored procedure?

Comment: In my opinion it would just be easier to structure my logic in VB.NET/C# and maintain this when compared to including that logic in the SQL source statement. If there is a calculated column whose value is used in calculating another column later on then I would have to repeat the first calculation in the second when trying to force it into the source SQL statement. In VB.NET/C# I can put the result of the first calculation into a variable and use the variable again later on.

Comment: If you were to use VB.NET/C# script how would you structure your SSIS? Where would you have your scrip component - Inside the DFT ? In this case your script task would be running for each row for the calculations which I would imagine would be slower.

Comment: Yes it would be inside the DFT. Unfortunately because my destination is a parent-child table with an autonumber my DFT is already row by row as I need to insert the parent and get the autonumber using an OUTPUT to insert the child. Where would you recommend placing all the calculations? Excuse my ignorance but placing them in the SQL source almost eliminates the need for SSIS as I may as well just insert straight into the destination. Maybe I am missing something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would build this as a Script - the VB.NET or C# syntax is much more elegant.  For example you can include Reflection and then loop over the set of input columns as an array, for repetitive logic - back in SQL you would have to duplicate code.

The performance hit is typically 10% slower than SQL CASE statements at worst.

Comment: That's great Mike that is what I was hoping to hear. Even the 10% performance hit at worst is worth the maintainability. At least I know I'm on the right track. Thanks